# Number of ways to choose + and - to make an equation correct

Tags: co.combinatorics

Say we had n non-zero real numbers $a_i$ and another real number b. What is the maximum number of ways to choose a + or a - for each number such that the equation:

$(+/-) a_1 (+/-) a_b ... (+/-)a_n = b$ is correct?

I believe the answer could be $\binom{n}{n/2}$ (imagine b=0 and all $a_i$ were the same) but I am not to sure how to explain this more formally.

Comment: "The maximal": maximal over what? what is fixed and what is not fixed? if all $a_i$, and $b$ are zero, all $2^n$ choices of sign work.

Comment: Forgot to mention that all $a_i$ must be non-zero.

Comment: So, the sup over all $n$-tuples $(a_i)$ of nonzero elements and $b$, if I get it correctly.

Comment: You might look at the Littlewood-Offord problem, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Littlewood-Offord_problem.

Comment: Yep! If I were to phrase it another way, how many ways can you choose $(c_1, ..., c_n) : c_i \in {-1, 1}$ and $\sum c_i \times a_i = b$

Comment: Please do not remove all content from the question.

Comment: @adamC If you want to delete, there's a button for that. If you can't use it for some reason, we can delete it for you. But please don't do it by manually destroying content.

Answer (score 4):

The answer is indeed ${n \choose \lfloor n/2 \rfloor}$, here is a proof.
It's equivalent to finding the maximal number of vectors $v$ in the hypercube $H=\{-1,1\}^n$ with all the same dot product with a fixed vector $a$ that has no coordinate zero.

By symmetry, we can assume that $a\in \mathbb{R}_{> 0}^n$. If we associate $v\in H$ to $S_v=\{i:v_i=1\} \subseteq [n]$, note that the $S_v$ form an antichain: indeed, if $(v+d)\cdot a = v\cdot a$ for $d\in \{0,2\}^n$, then $d\cdot a=0$ which is impossible unless $d=0$ (because $a\in \mathbb{R}_{> 0}^n$ and $d\in \mathbb{R}_{\ge 0}^n$).
Hence the result follows from Sperner's theorem.